# Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

```
public class ProgramDemoQA 
{

    public static WebDriver d;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "D:\\RamanaSoft\\PracticeCoding\\DemoQA\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        d = new ChromeDriver();
        d.get("https://demoqa.com");
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
        d.manage().window().maximize();
        
        
        
        d.findElement(By.xpath("//h5[text()='Elements']/../..")).click();
        d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Check Box']/..")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        d.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label=\'Toggle\']")).click();
        

        WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(d,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Desktop']/../../button")));

        WebElement Desktop = d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Desktop']/../../button"));



        WebDriverWait w1 = new WebDriverWait(d,Duration.ofSeconds(60));
        w1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(
                "//span[text()='Notes']//ancestor::label")));


        WebElement Notes = d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Notes']//ancestor::label"));



        WebDriverWait w2 = new WebDriverWait(d,Duration.ofSeconds(50));
        w2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(
                "//span[text()='Commands']//ancestor::label")));


        WebElement Commands= d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Commands']//ancestor::label"));

        if(Desktop.isDisplayed())
        {     
            Desktop.click();
            //Notes.click();
            Commands.click();
            System.out.println("All clicked"); 
        } 

        if(Desktop.isDisplayed())
        {
            //Desktop.click();
            Commands.click();

            System.out.println("Only Notes clicked"); 
        }


        if(Desktop.isDisplayed()) 
        {
            //Desktop.click();
            //  Notes.click();
            System.out.println("Only Commands clicked"); 
        }
```

I'm trying to automate https://demoqa.com/checkbox
clicked on toggle button of Home and tried to click Desktop  it's throwing an exception as below
Getting below:-

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //span[text()='Notes']//ancestor::label (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause of the issue:** You are waiting for the `Desktop` toggle to be visible and also you are capturing the element into a `WebElement` variable, however you forgot to `click()` on it. Since, you did not click on the Desktop toggle, `Notes` element was not visible. Hence below exception:

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //span[text()='Notes']//ancestor::label
```

**Solution:** Just click on the toggle as below so that `Notes` element is visible.

```
WebElement Desktop = d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Desktop']/../../button"));
Desktop.click();
```

**UPDATE:** I have refactored your code and removed unnecessary `Explicit Waits`. Check the below code:

```
WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
d.get("https://demoqa.com");
d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
d.manage().window().maximize();
        
// below line will click on Consent pop-up, if you do not get this pop-up just remove the line 
d.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Consent']")).click();
        
d.findElement(By.xpath("//h5[text()='Elements']/../..")).click();
d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Check Box']/..")).click();
d.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label=\'Toggle\']")).click();
WebElement Desktop = d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Desktop']/../../button"));
Desktop.click();

WebElement Notes = d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Notes']//ancestor::label"));
WebElement Commands= d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Commands']//ancestor::label"));

if(Desktop.isDisplayed())
    {     
        Notes.click();
        Commands.click();
        System.out.println("All clicked");
          
        // below line will un-check Commands checkbox
        Commands.click();
        System.out.println("Only Notes clicked");
            
        // below 2 lines will un-check Notes checkbox and check Commands checkbox
        Notes.click();
        Commands.click();
        System.out.println("Only Commands clicked");
    }
```

**Output:**

```
All clicked
Only Notes clicked
Only Commands clicked
```